# A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll on a combat simulator

Tags: vb.net

I have an issue trying to program a simple combat simulation for a project that I and another person is working on.

Module Module1

```
Dim Player_Vitality As Integer



Dim PlayerReiatsu As Integer
Dim PlayerZanjustu As Integer
Dim PlayerHakuda As Integer
Dim PlayerHoho As Integer
Dim PlayerKido As Integer
Dim PlayerAbility As Integer



Dim Player_Physical_Damage As Integer
Dim Player_Spirit_Damage As Integer
Dim Player_Critical_Chance As Integer
Dim Player_Critical_Damage As Integer





Sub Main()



    Call Shuhei()



End Sub





Sub Shuhei()

    Dim Shuhei_reiatsu As Integer
    Dim Shuhei_Vitality_TurnStart As Integer
    Dim Shuhei_Vitality_TurnEnd As Integer
    Dim Attack As String
    Dim Kido As Integer
    Dim Sword As Integer
    Dim Shuhei_Temp As Integer






    PlayerZanjustu = 40
    PlayerHakuda = 50
    PlayerKido = 50
    PlayerAbility = 75
    Shuhei_reiatsu = 80

    Kido = Player_Spirit_Damage
    Sword = Player_Physical_Damage

    'Player_Vitality = 100
    Shuhei_Vitality_TurnStart = 1000



    Console.WriteLine("FIGHT 1")
    Console.ReadLine()

    Do While Shuhei_Vitality_TurnStart > 0



        Player_Physical_Damage = ((PlayerZanjustu + PlayerHakuda) - Shuhei_reiatsu)
        Player_Spirit_Damage = ((PlayerKido + PlayerAbility) - Shuhei_reiatsu)
        'Player_Critical_Chance = ((PlayerZanjustu + PlayerHoho) - Shuhei_reiatsu) / 100
        'Player_Critical_Damage = (PlayerZanjustu + PlayerHakuda) * 10

        Shuhei_Temp = Shuhei_Vitality_TurnStart

        Console.WriteLine("Shuhei has " & Shuhei_Temp & "Hp")
        Console.WriteLine("Which attack do you want to use?")
        Attack = Console.ReadLine




        If Attack = "Kido" Or Kido Then

            Shuhei_Vitality_TurnEnd = ((Shuhei_Temp) - Player_Spirit_Damage)
        ElseIf Attack = "Sword" Or Sword Then

            Shuhei_Vitality_TurnEnd = Shuhei_Temp - Player_Physical_Damage

        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Please choose an attack")

        End If

        Shuhei_Vitality_TurnEnd = Shuhei_Vitality_TurnStart
        If Shuhei_Vitality_TurnStart <= 0 Then
            Call FightEnd()
        End If
    Loop

    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

Sub FightEnd()
    Console.WriteLine("Shuhei has been defeated")
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

This is all copied down to the point in a new sub where there is deactivated junk with no purpose as of yet, so I doubt that is the issue, it is just the skeleton of the combat code but with ' in front to disable it. Then at the bottom the End Module command

Comment: `If Attack = "Kido" Or Kido Then` should be `If Attack = "Kido" Or Attack = Kido Then` you have to eval each expression of the `Or` or an `And` operator.

Comment: @DaveDev - nope `Dim Shuhei_reiatsu As Integer` is `VB.NET` for sure in C# it would have been `integer Shuhei_reiatsu;`

Comment: @logixologist C# would have been `int`

Comment: oops yes you are right.... I rely too much on intellisense

Comment: I just took what the site suggested for tag

Answer (score 0):

In your `IF` Statement `Attack` could really never be `"Kido"` or `Kido`. You are comparing a string to a string or a string to an integer and that is likely your issue. Try converting Kido the variable to a string and that might supress the error.

Pseudo code:

```
If Attack = "Kido" Or Kido.ToString
```

Comment: Fixed it the formula must have been multiplying the zangustu and hakuda total by the negative reiatsu value